# Mysql: de-normalize a table or create a view?

Tags: mysql, database, view

In mysql database I have three tables with these relationships: `users--rents--places--users`.

These relationships represent a *user* that can make *rents* on a particular *place* and the *place* is owned by a owner (which is a also a *user*).

Since the *rents* must be accepted by the owner I'm in the situation where I have to collect all the owner's rents.

My concern is about what's best to do in terms of simplicity and logical correctiveness. I mean, is easy to retrieve *rents* in the right-left direction of the relationships (as written above) but I think that it's not correct in terms of what I need and how I get it.

So, I was thinking about 2 options to collect the owner's rents in a better way:

1. de-normalize the `rents` table by adding the `owner_id` to it.
2. create a view `owners_rents` which exposes `owner_id` and `rent_id` by selecting from the right-left direction of the relationships

I never used views on database. I was asking myself if the point 2 is a good use case for views in terms of clarity and performance.

Comment: Never denormalize. What advantage do you see? If a place has an owner, that information belongs to that table. If you need it somewhere else, do a join. You can of course use a view for that, a view is just an abbreviation for a select; not sure if it's "a good use case" though as it isn't much shorter or clearer. On the other hand, you might need two users at "rent"-level, because a contract doesn't have to be between a tenant and the owner of a place, but maybe a manager, but CAN be the owner. This depends on your requirements (and laws in your country). And wouldn't be denormalization.

Comment: you're right. I would have call it *de-normalization* but it's true that in this way it takes another meaning which best suits my requirements